# How do I fix this apache error log issue? Mod Deflate

Tags: apache

I'm getting the following errors in my erorr.log file on every request

[Fri Jan 29 14:44:17 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(619): [client 10.128.99.99] Zlib: Compressed 6025 to 1847 : URL

about 2 gigs worth (high load server)

any idea what this error is referring to?

Comment: *is* it an error? Looks to me as a debug output log message from a deflate module that just logs how much it was able to compress some data.

Comment: I tried setting my loglevel to error but it's still throwing those debug messages in there so I'm not sure if it's a real error or a debug warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you only have LogLevel specified once, or that you're changing it for the correct virtual host.  And you'll need to kick apache of course.

Answer (score 1):

doh! just found it... someone had set a specific error log for this particular virtual host and the loglevel was set to debug.

Comment: so this isn't an error and is outputted to the error log just as additional info?